# How do I access just the second part of these arrays in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I use the following function so I can select 2 rows in a table:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cellId = indexPath.row
    //print (self.communityPlayerIds[indexPath.row])

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")
        if sr.count == 2{
            print ("one ", sr[0])
            print ("two ", sr[1])
        }
    }


}
```

the `print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")` line outputs something like this:

> didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:[[0, 2], [0, 3]]

I want to access the second int only in each array (discarding the 0's).  I have tried using `print ("one ", sr[0])` to attempt this but this outputs the following:

> one  [0, 2]

In the example above I only want to access the `2` so I can store that in a separate variable.

How can I access the second part only of these arrays?  (the 2, and 3)

Comment: `sr[0][1]` perhaps?

Comment: Excellent Matt! Thankyou! That was simple ;)

Comment: I *think* `sr.row` would also do it, `sr` is index path, which contains both `section` and `row`. 0 is the section and 1,2 are the rows

Comment: There are two answers below - please mark one as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an array containing just the second numbers, you can use a `map`, like this:

```
sr.map { $0[1] }
```

Or, since they are index paths, this is neater:

```
sr.map { $0.row }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, `sr = [[0,2],[0,3]]` ?

If so, you have two arrays.

```
let firstArray = sr[0]
//you will see this would print as [0,2]
let numberTwo = firstArray[1]
//you will see this would print as 2
```